# SQL append strings

Tags: mysql, sql

how to insert a string from a particular position in another string to a column in database.Like i have column named Name in table world.Name column has a value Test.How to insert in the string name from 2nd postion that is from after e in test.Like test should become tenewst.

```
Database name :World
Table Name    :Name
A Value in Name Table: Test
Desired output: Te-New-st- 
(That is adding string "New" afer 2nd position in "Test" string.)
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using SQL developer or mysql workbech.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server

```
 --Original String
 DECLARE @orgString varchar(50) = 'This is some test string'
 --Search String
 DECLARE @searchString varchar(50) = 'te'
 --String to insert into the original string
 DECLARE @insertString varchar(50) = 'NEW'

 SELECT 
 CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@orgString,1,CHARINDEX(@searchString,@orgString)+1),
            @insertString,
 SUBSTRING(@orgString,CHARINDEX(@searchString,@orgString)+2,LEN(@orgString))) 
 AS String
```

To run something like this against data in your table, replace the original string variable with your column name

```
 --Search String
 DECLARE @searchString varchar(50) = 'te'
 --String to insert into the original string
 DECLARE @insertString varchar(50) = 'NEW'

 SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Name,1,CHARINDEX(@searchString,Name)+1),
            @insertString,
 SUBSTRING(Name,CHARINDEX(@searchString,Name)+2,LEN(Name))) 
 AS String
 FROM Table_1
```

If it is **ALWAYS** going to be between the 2nd and 3rd position, you could simplify it a little to this.

```
 --String to insert into the original string
 DECLARE @insertString varchar(50) = 'NEW'

 SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Name,1,2),
               @insertString,
              SUBSTRING(Name,3,LEN(Name))) 
          AS String
 FROM Table_1
```

Check out this for string function references, [String Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql)